# UIView dynamic height depending on Label Height

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift2, uilabel

I have a Label which takes dynamicaly some data from database.
These data are strings which can sometimes be 3-4-5 rows etc.
So this labe is inside a UIView.

```
--UIView
  --Label
```

How can i make the `UIView` to take the certain height of the Label dynamicaly??

Comment: Try using the auto layout as described [here](http://www.programmingcrew.in/2015/09/uitable-view-cell-dynamic-height-ios7.html)

Comment: @pkc456 i have nothing to do with TableView and Cells. It's just a simple view!

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios see my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can just do it with storyboard this pics

[image]

[image]

set the label height relation to greater than or equal

and set the view  height relation to greater than or equal

it work like a magic

Comment: why it's are you set both label and view height constant  relation to greater than or equal

Comment: Yes i set them both !

Comment: i think you fix the bottom constant of your view . not give bottom constant of uiview.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is late answer, but it might help someone else.
To make the Dynamic height for UIView follow the simple steps in Storyboard

1. Add a UIView in UIViewController and set your favourite background colour

[image]

2. Now set the following constraints Leading, Top, Trailing and Height(as of now). We can adjust the Height constraint to achieve dynamic height further.
   [image]
3. Update Height Constraints as shown below:
   [image]
4. Now probably there storyboard will show you inequality constraint ambiguity. But we are going to fix this now. Just add a label inside UIView as shown
   [image]
5. Now Set the Constraints for Label Leading, Trailing, Top and Bottom
   [image]
6. Hurrah, Now the UIView height will increase based on the label's height. just make the following changes to label
   [image]

This technique works with other views inside this UIView. The thing is you must specify bottom constraints for the views present inside this UIView.

Answer (score 6):

Bellow is working solution of your problem. I used `autoLayout`. In `testView` you don't set `heightAnchor`

```
let testView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    return view
}()

let testLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.text = "jashfklhaslkfhaslkjdhflksadhflkasdhlkasdhflkadshkfdsjh"
    return label
}()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(testView)
    testView.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.centerXAnchor).active = true
    testView.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.centerYAnchor).active = true
    testView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(100).active = true


    testView.addSubview(testLabel)
    testLabel.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(testView.topAnchor, constant: 10).active = true
    testLabel.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(testView.leftAnchor, constant: 10).active = true
    testLabel.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(testView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).active = true
    testLabel.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(testView.rightAnchor, constant: -10).active = true

}
```

Comment: Hi Reference to your autolayout answer, can I ask one question please?

Answer (score 3):

first calculate the size of label with the text it contains, using this function

```
func calculateSizeOfLabel(text:String,labelWidth:CGFloat,labelFont:UIFont)->CGSize{
        let constrainedSize = CGSizeMake(labelWidth , 9999)

        var attributesDictionary:[String:AnyObject] = [:]

            attributesDictionary = [NSFontAttributeName:labelFont] as [String:AnyObject]



        let string:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:text, attributes:attributesDictionary)

        var boundingRect = string.boundingRectWithSize(constrainedSize, options:.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, context:nil)

        if (boundingRect.size.width > labelWidth) {
            boundingRect = CGRectMake(0,0, labelWidth, boundingRect.size.height);
        }


    return boundingRect.size
}
```

and then apply the height of returned size to the UIView like this

```
    let labelText = description.text
    let labelWidth = description.bounds.width
    let labelFont = description.font
    let calculatedHeight = calculateSizeOfLabel(labelText,labelWidth:labelWidth,labelFont:labelFont).height 
    DescView.frame = CGRectMake(DescView.frame.origin.x, DescView.frame.origin.y, DescView.bounds.width,calculatedHeight)
```

Comment: Lets say that the UILabel is `description` how can i call your function to set the view `DescView` heigh as the labels height?

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios I've updated my answer.please go through it.

Comment: thanks for the update and the answer but i get 2 errors
1) `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not UIFont` in the line ` if let font = labelFont{`
And the second error is in this line `DescView.frame = CGRectMake(DescView.frame.origin.x, DescView.frame.origin.y, DescView.bounds.width,calculatedHeight)` Where it says `Cannot convert value of type CGSize to expected argument type CGFloat`

Comment: Ok the second error is resolved if I edit it to `calculatedHeight.height` But the first one i dont know

Comment: New error `Use of unresolved undentifier `font` on line `attributesDictionary = [NSFontAttributeName:font] as [String:AnyObject]`

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios please see updated answer.now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Below code will resolved your issue :

//Adjust View Height

```
[yourView setFrame:CGRectMake(yourView.frame.origin.x, yourView.frame.origin.y, yourView.frame.size.width, yourLable.frame.size.height + yourLable.frame.origin.y + extraspace)];
```

Comment: in swift maybe?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)action:(id)sender {
self.label.text = @"UIImage *imageOne = [UIImage imageNamed:@RosePot.jpUIImageJPEGRepresentationg";
NSLog(@"%f",self.label.bounds.size.height);

float height = [self getHeightForText:@"UIImage *imageOne = [UIImage imageNamed:@RosePot.jpUIImageJPEGRepresentationg" withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:15] andWidth:self.label.bounds.size.width];
NSLog(@"%f",height);
self.constraint.constant = height + self.viewOne.bounds.size.height;
```

}

```
-(float) getHeightForText:(NSString*) text withFont:(UIFont*) font andWidth:(float) width{
CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(width , 20000.0f);
CGSize title_size;
float totalHeight;

SEL selector = @selector(boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:);
if ([text respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    title_size = [text boundingRectWithSize:constraint
                                    options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                 attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : font }
                                    context:nil].size;

    totalHeight = ceil(title_size.height);
} else {
    title_size = [text sizeWithFont:font
                  constrainedToSize:constraint
                      lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    totalHeight = title_size.height ;
}

CGFloat height = MAX(totalHeight, 40.0f);
return height;
```

}

[image]

Give leading ,top, trailing and height constraint for view .

And height outlet of view name as constraint [because i used outlet name constraint]

Answer (score 0):

Add **left**, **top**, **right**, and **bottom** constraints of the label to the view.

Set this property for the view

```
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

The view height will be dynamic by the label content size.