# UILabel Autoshrink with top constraints

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel, autosize

I try to figure out autoshrink option in UILabel with regarding top constraint.

I have UIView and three labels. One of them has autoshrink option on. It has constraint to be centered, and has Trailing and Top constraint which should shrink label when changing size of UIView. If I make UIVIew thinner, font size is decreased, but if I change height of UIView font is not changed.

Constraints on UILabels :

- Align Center X to Superview
- Align Center Y to Superview
- Trailing Space to Superview >= 50
- Top Space to Superview >= 40
- Align Center X to label2
- Top Space to label1 equals :15
- Bottom space to label2 equals :3

Label 1 constraints :

- Align Center x to superview
- Trailing Space to superview >=10
- Leading Space to superview >=10
- Bottom Space to Shrink Label equal 15

Label 2 constraint :

- Align Center X to Shrink label
- Top Space to Shrink label equals 3

How to change this?

What I want is, on last image that label will be nice autoshrink. So if I change width or height of the UIView label should shrink.

[image: Normal size]

[image: Width change]

[image: Height change]

Comment: Can you explain it more .

Comment: sure, what do you need to know.

Comment: are you want shrink label change according to view ?

Comment: Yes. If you look last image you can see that shrink is not what I want

Comment: ok i got it plz wait for answer.

Comment: I am waiting :D thanks

Comment: can you show txt1 and txt2 constraint?

Comment: I edit my question, but there is no real importance in label 1,2 constraint

Comment: Check the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

plz select your Shrink label set

**Number of lines is 0**

**Line Breaks: Clip**

**Autoshrink: Minimum Font Scale 0.25**
[image]

Comment: This is working,.. could you provide reasons, why there is need to set number of lines 0 and line break to clip,...

Comment: If you set line 1 then label height will not change dynamically so you have to set it with 0. and in line breaks you can use also TurnCate head ,tail, mid.

Comment: For label Dynamic height you can see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410796/uiview-dynamic-height-depending-on-label-height/39411166#39411166

Answer (score 1):

I hope below code will help you in some way,

```
extension Double {
    /// Returns propotional width according to device width
    var propotional: CGFloat {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
            return CGFloat(414.0) / CGFloat(375.0) * CGFloat(self)
        }
        return CGFloat(Screen.width) / CGFloat(375.0) * CGFloat(self)
    }
}



extension UILabel {
        /// This property is change font-size of Label's text propotionaly, if assigned `On` from Interface builder
       @IBInspectable
        var isPropotional: Bool{
            get {
                return true
            }

        set {
                if newValue == true {
                    let fontSize = Double((self.font!.pointSize))
                    self.font = UIFont(name: self.font!.fontName, size: fontSize.propotional)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In extension of Double, propotional value is calculated by considering current device set in storyboard as iPhone 6 size.

[image]
After adding this code set `on` from interface builder for Label where you can see isPropotional attribute in attribute inspector tab. Please refer image.