# swift 3 ios : UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I'm trying to create a `UILabel`, with dynamic height

**this is my code :**

```
        label1.text = Message
        label1.textColor = UIColor.white
        let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)
        label1.font = font
        label1.textAlignment = .center
        label1.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping;
        label1.numberOfLines = 0;
        label1.sizeToFit()

        label1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:40 , width: 270, height: label1.frame.height)
```

however, my `label` stay with one line, where my Message is about 3 lines
so what could be the best solution for this problem?

Comment: Have you given any constraints to your UILabel?

Comment: plz see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410796/uiview-dynamic-height-depending-on-label-height/39411166#39411166

Comment: you just need to set the label height relation to greater than or equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
let size = label1.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: 270, height: 100000))
label1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 40, width: 270, height: size.height)
```

for the last two line of your code.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be using constraints.

Either directly in the InterfaceBuilder or via code.
([SnapKit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit) would be a good and easy way to build constraints via code)

Comment: In a constraint based layout you need no constraints for the height. Constraints for position and width will be enough. Autolayout will calculate the height automatically.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with storyboard
[image]

label height relation to **greater than or equal**